# how do i check the flow of Android Tv or full built Android App that is being used as Product

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

We have an app that is used as product means that we customize the main app and depoly it according to client needs . It is a fully built product/ App i need to understand the flow of it .

I started with checking Android Mainifest and then start checking Activities and their functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your question, but I will try to answer with few possible ways.

1. Full build flow
   You can run "Rebuild Project" and your "Build" tab will display a full list of gradle tasks being run:
   [image: Rebuild flow]
2. You have mentioned Android TV in the question title, so I assume you might have two modules (app and tv) and you wonder how they interact with each other. By default they do not. But if they would, you could see it in the build.gradle (at the module level) under dependencies. Otherwise, one does not run thecode of the other.

[image: Dependencies]
[image: Modules]

3. Android Profiler
   You could use the profiler tool to diagnose which methods are being run when the app is running, just head to "Profiler" tool, click on CPU, then Select CPU Profiling mode as "Trace Java/Kotlin Method Trace", click "Record" and when you are done click "Stop". Investigate from here.[image]
4. At the start your Application class will be run (if you have extended the default one), then it runs the activity that has intent-filter set as main launcher in the AndroidManifest.xml file. From here you can set debug breakpoints and run the app in the debug mode or insert code that will log into console.

Comment: Thanks It helped if you want to  add to it ,Please tell